# html helper checkbox not working as required

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have a questionnaire, on first page if user selects the checkbox (generated by below code)

in the next page it should not be checked and when user goes back to previous it should be checked. nothing is working, while debugging the view it shows everything getting executed properly but when the page is displayed checkbox is ticked for any question user goes through... I don't know  why this html helper is not working, I have tried everything.

In other words :
I have a problem with ASP.NET core web app MVC where CheckBoxFor would not check my checkboxes on server-side validation failure even though my model clearly had the value set to true. My Razor markup/code looked like:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.markforreview, Model.markforreview)<label>Mark For Review</label>
```

Comment: Are you passing object While redirecting to the previous page or next page? Otherwise, you have to save the data in tempData so whenever you redirect get it and assign to model and return.

Comment: Yes I am passing the data, even at the time of rendering condition is correct but check box always comes with a tick?

Comment: Does `@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.markforreview)` work? Is `markforreview` a non-nullable boolean?

Comment: Did you check it with question id, means while assigning mark for review to checkbox check which question it is then using Linq get its corresponding value and assign

Comment: it's non nullable, and it does have true/false always. markforreview is bound by model so when the user changes the checkbox it comes in a model, even while rendering I can see the model value true/false but in a view it's always rendering as checked.

Answer (score 0):

I added

ModelState.Clear();
before all return view();

@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.markforreview)
is working now.